# I want to add libnl1 to Ubuntu 18.04. Is there a way?

Tags: 18.04, software-installation

We are running Ubuntu 18.04, and need to add The Netlink Library libnl1 to the installation.  Does anyone know how to do this? I am looking for a *tested* procedure.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible by using packages from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Open terminal and type:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libn/libnl/libnl1_1.1-8ubuntu1_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libn/libnl/libnl-dev_1.1-8ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./libnl1_1.1-8ubuntu1_amd64.deb ./libnl-dev_1.1-8ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```